# How do I programmatically provide scope to angular.bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Consider the following code

```
var el = angular.element('<div>{{variable}}</div>');
$(document.body).append(el);
angular.bootstrap(el);
```

Is there a way to specify initial scope's `variable` value. So that when the appended angular application bootstrapped - it already has this variable available there?

Comment: bootstrap takes a module name and currently it is buggy. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545204/manually-bootstrapping-angularjs-and-then-getting-the-module/18367931#18367931

Comment: Would creating values/constants in your app be out of the question?

Comment: Phix, it should be adjustable when I call angular.bootstrap(). So it changes depending on `el`.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Module.run](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.Module#run) method:

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.variable = 'init value';
})
```

Comment: This will change global variable for every app that uses this module, but what if I need this app available to the scope of app rooted to `el`?

Comment: Why not to put it into `el`'s scope then?